# Request SQL doesn't apply conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I am doing a SQL request on this table :

[image]

This is the request :

```
SELECT event_datetime as day, event_param_2 as R1, event_param_3 as Content, event_code
FROM events
WHERE upcNameId = 'ExampleName'
AND event_param_2 = 1
AND event_datetime >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
AND event_datetime <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
AND event_code = 51 OR event_code = 52 OR event_code = 53 OR event_code = 54
```

And this is the result I get from this :

[image]

My question is simple, how can I get other numbers than 1 in the R1 column since I explicitly said that it had to be 1 ?

Comment: That is because of operator precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
SELECT event_datetime as day, event_param_2 as R1, event_param_3 as Content, event_code
FROM events
WHERE upcNameId = 'ExampleName'
AND event_param_2 = 1
AND event_datetime >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
AND event_datetime <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
AND (event_code = 51 OR event_code = 52 OR event_code = 53 OR event_code = 54)
```

Alternatively, use `IN`:

```
SELECT event_datetime as day, event_param_2 as R1, event_param_3 as Content, event_code
FROM events
WHERE upcNameId = 'ExampleName'
AND event_param_2 = 1
AND event_datetime >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
AND event_datetime <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
AND event_code IN(51, 52, 53, 54)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT event_datetime as day, event_param_2 as R1, event_param_3 as Content, event_code
FROM events
WHERE upcNameId = 'ExampleName'
AND event_param_2 = 1
AND event_datetime >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
AND event_datetime <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
AND event_code in (51,52,53,54)
```

try this, because of your "OR" in the where part, it will include everything as long as it fulfilled one of the condition under "OR"